# differentiation of difficult function with unknown constants

Tags: calculus

The expression

$C = -A\frac{\frac{K1}{f1^2H}+2\frac{K1K2}{f1^2f2H^2}+3\frac{K1K2K3}{f1^3f3H^3}}{1+\frac{K1}{f1^2H}+\frac{K1K2}{f1^2f2H^2}+\frac{K1K2K3}{f1^3f3H^3}}$

where A is a positive constant, K1,K2,K3 are positive constants such that K1>K2>K3, and f1,f2,f3 are positive constants such that f1>f2>f3 shows the net negative charge on a trivalent acid with Ks being dissociation constants and fs being activity coefficients. When plotted with arbitrary values for Ks and fs the C is always increasing as H increases.

Now I have two problems, the first is whether I could show that C is always monotone increasing with H, e.g. that the 
$\frac{dC}{dH}$
is always positive.
The second is if I can always know that if I have an arbitrary number of functions each monotone in the same direction, the sum of such functions will also be monotone.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can compute the $\frac{dC}{dH}$ explicitly and see that it is positive for $H>0$, depending on what $H$ is it can help. For your second question, just use that $\frac{d(C+B)}{dH} = \frac{dC}{dH} + \frac{dB}{dH}$ and the positivity of the RHS.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I tried to differentiate C using Maxima but couldn't make it work - H is positive, so thanks a lot also for the monotone solution

Comment: In Maple it worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'll see if I can find the money :-) - wonder if an open source program might do the trick

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ ;) Just tried there and it worked.

Comment: var('A H f1 f2 f3 K1 K2 K3'); 
C=-A*((K1)/(f1^2*H)+2*(K1*K2)/(f1^2*f2*H^2)+3*(K1*K2*K3)/(f1^3*f3*H^3))/(1+(K1)/(f1^2*H)+(K1*K2)/(f1^2*f2*H^2)+(K1*K2*K3)/(f1^3*f3*H^3));
diff(C,H)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference and the code - it works for me as well although it is not easy for me to see that the long expression is necessarily positive for H>0 and all constants positive since we get both a positive and a negative term. Most of the K and H are indeed very small  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can simplify this function
$$
C(H) = -A\frac{\frac{K_1}{f_1^2H}+2\frac{K_1K_2}{f_1^2f_2H^2}+3\frac{K_1K_2K_3}{f_1^3f_3H^3}}{1+\frac{K_1}{f_1^2H}+\frac{K_1K_2}{f_1^2f_2H^2}+\frac{K_1K_2K_3}{f_1^3f_3H^3}}
$$
multiplying numerator and denominator by $f_1^3f_2f_3H^3$:
$$
C(H) = -A\frac{K_1f_1f_2f_3H^2+2K_1K_2f_1f_3H+3K_1K_2K_3f_2}{f_1^3f_2f_3H^3+K_1f_1f_2f_3H^2+K_1K_2f_1f_3H+K_1K_2K_3f_2}
$$
Then
$$
 \frac{dC}{dH} = {\frac {AK_{{1}}f_{{1}}f_{{2}}f_{{3}} \left( {f_{{1}}}^{3}{H}^{4}f_{{2}}f_{{3}}+4\,{H}^{3}K_{{2}}{f_{{1}}}^{3}f_{{3
}}+ \left( 9\,K_{{2}}K_{{3}}{f_{{1}}}^{2}f_{{2}}+K_{{1}}K_{{2}}f_{{1}}
f_{{3}} \right) {H}^{2}+4\,HK_{{1}}K_{{2}}K_{{3}}f_{{2}}+K_{{1}}{K_{{2
}}}^{2}K_{{3}}
 \right) }{ \left( {H
}^{3}{f_{{1}}}^{3}f_{{2}}f_{{3}}+{H}^{2}K_{{1}}f_{{1}}f_{{2}}f_{{3}}+H
K_{{1}}K_{{2}}f_{{1}}f_{{3}}+K_{{1}}K_{{2}}K_{{3}}f_{{2}} \right)^{2}
}}
$$
And you can verify it is positive for $H>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot again - but var('A H f1 f2 f3 K1 K2 K3'); C=-A*(K1*f1*f2*f3*H^2 + 2*K1*K2*f1*f3*H + 3*K1*K2*K3*f2)/(f1^3*f2*f3*H^3 + K1*f1*f2*f3*H^2 + K1*K2*f1*f3*H + K1*K2*K3*f2);diff(C,H) gave me a muchmore ugly result

Comment: maybe because of the formula for the derivative of a quotient...

Comment: Thanks a lot - I have tried for hours using the quotient formula but cannot get your result; also I would guess Sage Cell server knew that rule - I wonder where is my error??

Comment: Focusing only on the numerator in the quotient above
var('A','K1','K2','K3','f1','f2','f3','H'); B = -A*(K1*f1*f2*f3*H^2+2*K1*K2*f1*f3*H+3*K1*K2*K3*f2);D=f1^3*f2*f3*H^3+K1*f1*f2*f3*H^2+K1*K2*f1*f3*H+K1*K2*K3*f2;diff(B,H)*D-diff(D,H)*B
which gives
(3*H^2*f1^3*f2*f3 + 2*H*K1*f1*f2*f3 + K1*K2*f1*f3)*(H^2*K1*f1*f2*f3 + 2*H*K1*K2*f1*f3 + 3*K1*K2*K3*f2)*A - 2*(H^3*f1^3*f2*f3 + H^2*K1*f1*f2*f3 + H*K1*K2*f1*f3 + K1*K2*K3*f2)*(H*K1*f1*f2*f3 + K1*K2*f1*f3)*A
Since all K are positive and less than 1 and all f likewise I can see this is positive - but it's far less elegant than found above -

Comment: I got Mable and I am happy to confirm the results of Alan including that the derivative is positive - THANKS a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :)