# Differential of iterative function

Tags: calculus

I previously got great help with understanding that

$$C = -A\frac{\frac{K1}{f1^2H}+2\frac{K1K2}{f1^2f2H^2}+3\frac{K1K2K3}{f1^3f3H^3}}{1+\frac{K1}{f1^2H}+\frac{K1K2}{f1^2f2H^2}+\frac{K1K2K3}{f1^3f3H^3}}$$

always had a positive differential in H ([differentiation of difficult function with unknown constants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936462/differentiation-of-difficult-function-with-unknown-constants))

Now I wonder if we can generalize - the general next entry in the numerator would be

$$i\frac{K1K2...Ki}{f1^ifiH^i}$$ and the next entry in the denominator would be

$$\frac{K1K2...Ki}{f1^ifiH^i}$$ - it seems also from actual numeric experimenttion that it is indeed true that the general differential is still positive - but can we prove that?

I should add that all K and f values are positive and H (proton concentration) is also positive. K values are true thermodynamic constants, and f values, activity coefficients are assumed fixed for each value of total buffer concentration (A) as a first approximation.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a proof.*

Let $H=\frac 1x$ and consider the function
$$f=\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n i\, a_i\, x^i}{1+\sum _{i=1}^n a_i\, x^i}$$ Compute the derivative to get 
$$\left(1+\sum _{i=1}^n a_i\, x^i \right)^2\, f'=\left(\sum _{i=1}^n i^2 a_i x^{i-1}\right) \left(1+\sum _{i=1}^n a_i
   x^i\right)-\left(\sum _{i=1}^n i a_i x^{i-1}\right)\left( \sum _{i=1}^n i a_i
   x^i\right)$$ The rhs is then a polynomial of degree $2(n-1)$ that is to say

$$\text{rhs}=\sum_{i=0}^{2(n-1)} b_i\,x^i$$ in which the coefficients are all positive since all $a_i$'s are non negative. For example, using $n=10$, we should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i & b_i \\
 0 & a_1 \\
 1 & 4 a_2 \\
 2 & a_1 a_2+9 a_3 \\
 3 & 4 a_1 a_3+16 a_4 \\
 4 & a_2 a_3+9 a_1 a_4+25 a_5 \\
 5 & 4 a_2 a_4+16 a_1 a_5+36 a_6 \\
 6 & a_3 a_4+9 a_2 a_5+25 a_1 a_6+49 a_7 \\
 7 & 4 a_3 a_5+16 a_2 a_6+36 a_1 a_7+64 a_8 \\
 8 & a_4 a_5+9 a_3 a_6+25 a_2 a_7+49 a_1 a_8+81 a_9 \\
 9 & 4 a_4 a_6+16 a_3 a_7+36 a_2 a_8+64 a_1 a_9+100 a_{10} \\
 10 & a_5 a_6+9 a_4 a_7+25 a_3 a_8+49 a_2 a_9+81 a_1 a_{10} \\
 11 & 4 a_5 a_7+16 a_4 a_8+36 a_3 a_9+64 a_2 a_{10} \\
 12 & a_6 a_7+9 a_5 a_8+25 a_4 a_9+49 a_3 a_{10} \\
 13 & 4 a_6 a_8+16 a_5 a_9+36 a_4 a_{10} \\
 14 & a_7 a_8+9 a_6 a_9+25 a_5 a_{10} \\
 15 & 4 a_7 a_9+16 a_6 a_{10} \\
 16 & a_8 a_9+9 a_7 a_{10} \\
 17 & 4 a_8 a_{10} \\
 18 & a_9 a_{10}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot - but what is then the interpretation in regard tothe question of whether we caan know if thederivativeis positive?

Comment: @user37217. You have sums of only positive terms.

Comment: Thanks a lot - so this is indeed a proof?  - nice!!!